# Google chrome page load stuck on two windows 10 machines

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a strange problem with google chrome (latest version but I had the problem on previous version) on two windows 10 version 1909 Machines, on any other machine on the network I don't have this problem.

- When I start chrome, if I open immediately youtube and play something I cannot open other sites. If I open another site in another tab the site load gets stuck on the first request.
- If I don't open youtube, site load works but after some point in time, on new tabs site load stops working

Inspecting Network with developer tools I see that first request gets stuck in "Request sent" so any following request can't start. The other strange thing is that Performance tab tool doesn't work when the page is in this state. Page refresh obviously doesn't get things work.

I tried:

- Uninstalling antivirus
- Disabling windows firewall
- Using another computer account
- Creating and using another chrome "Person"
- Clearing cache

Any advice?

Thank you

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved reinstalling chrome after uninstalling it with the remove all personal data flag checked